# VHDL signals are U

Tags: vhdl

I am using Questa Sim to produce an ALU, the ALU can for the moment only subtract. I am able to compile the file, but when I simulate all the signals are U, do you see how I can fix that?

```
    library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED.ALL;
    
    
    entity ALU is
        port(A,B: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
             ALUControl: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
             Result: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
    end;
    
    architecture synth of ALU is
    signal neg: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0);
    signal negtemp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal sum: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal sum1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0);
    signal resulttemp :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0);
    begin
    negtemp <= (not B);
    neg <= ('0' & negtemp(31 downto 0));
    sum1 <= '0' & A;
    
    
    
    process(ALUControl,A,B) begin
    if ALUControl = "01" then
        resulttemp <= sum1+neg;
        Result <= resulttemp(31 downto 0);
    end if;
    end process;
    
    
    end;
```

testbench:

```
library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity tb5 is
end;

architecture behaveorial of tb5 is
component ALU
port(A,B: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
         ALUControl: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
         Result: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
end component;
signal tA,tB: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
signal tALUControl: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
signal tResult: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);

begin
dut: ALU port map(tA,tB,tALUControl, tResult);
process begin
tA<="00000000000000000000000000000011"; wait for 10 ns;
tB<="00000000000000000000000000000001";wait for 10 ns;
tALUControl <= "01"; 
wait for 100 ns;
assert tResult ="00000000000000000000000000000010" report "failure11";
wait;



end process;



end;
```

**UPDATE: If I remove the if condition it works fine, so something is wrong with the if condition?**

Comment: Have a read of this question and [its answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308986/initialising-input-signals-in-vhdl/308989#308989) on initialising D-type flip-flops (DFFs) using a reset

Answer (score 1):

*This doesn't try to answer your question. However, it will improve your design which may then take you closer to your solution...*

First, in your VHDL, use indentation and don't put more than one statement on one line. A clear and conventional source file layout makes it easier for you and others to work on it and to spot mistakes in it.

Your existing design process only produces a `Result` when `ALUControl` is `01`. That process will produce combinatorial logic i.e. a circuit made from AND, OR, XOR and NOT gate functions. Combinatorial logic circuits always produce an output for every combination of input values, whereas yours wasn't.

Try modifying your process to the following.

```
  pALUResult : process is
  begin
    case ALUControl is

      when  "01"  =>    resulttemp  <=  sum1 + neg;
                        Result      <=  resulttemp(31 downto  0);

      when others =>    Result      <=  X"00000000";

    end case;
  end process pALUResult;
```

This can be expanded as you add more ALU functions. Try testing it.